# Getting the previous record in MySQL as sorted by a value, not by index (MySQL 5.6.40)

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table `fruit` like this:

```
|        text | id | time_end | parent_id |
| ------------|----|----------|-----------|
| banana tree | 23 |      200 |         7 |
| tomato vine | 84 |      500 |         7 |
|   pear tree | 13 |      800 |         7 |
|  apple tree | 40 |     1000 |         7 |
|  grape vine | 15 |     1800 |         7 |
```

Now let's say I had a query that did a LIKE search. E.G.:
`SELECT id, time_end FROM fruit WHERE text LIKE '%tree';`

That would give me the data for `banana tree`, `pear tree`, and `apple tree`.

But suppose I wanted the data before each row, using the two-column index of `time_end`+`parent_id`. How do I do that with a minimum number of queries? In the example here, the output should be:

```
|        text | id | time_end | time_start | parent_id |
|-------------|----|----------|------------|-----------|
| banana tree | 23 |      200 |          0 |         7 |
|   pear tree | 13 |      800 |        500 |         7 |
|  apple tree | 40 |     1000 |        800 |         7 |
```

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: 5.6.40. Question updated.

Comment: Is there a column that explicitly describes the sort order? time_end perhaps?

Comment: time_end, but only within its own parent_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8aebd/7)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE fruit
    (`text` varchar(11), `id` int, `time_end` int, `parent_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO fruit
    (`text`, `id`, `time_end`, `parent_id`)
VALUES
    ('banana tree', 23, 200, 7),
    ('tomato vine', 84, 500, 7),
    ('pear tree', 13, 800, 7),
    ('apple tree', 40, 1000, 7),
    ('grape vine', 15, 1800, 7)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
 SELECT a.text,a.id, a.time_end,
 IFNULL((select max(time_end) from fruit where time_end < a.time_end),0) as time_start,
 a.parent_id 
 FROM fruit a WHERE a.text LIKE '%tree'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8aebd/7/0)**:

```
|        text | id | time_end | time_start | parent_id |
|-------------|----|----------|------------|-----------|
| banana tree | 23 |      200 |          0 |         7 |
|   pear tree | 13 |      800 |        500 |         7 |
|  apple tree | 40 |     1000 |        800 |         7 |
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great. Just one more request... is there some way to make the "a" the inner table instead of the outer table?

Comment: @Agamemnus Yeah sure, just do it like this `IFNULL((select max(a.time_end) from fruit a where a.time_end < fruit.time_end),0) as time_start`